# jQuery, click element inside clickable element

Tags: jquery, click

I have HTML syntax as followed :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="click1">
      <a href="somelink.html" id="click2">
        here's the link
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I have jquery syntax like this

```
$('td#click1').ajaxify();
$('a#click2').fancybox();
```

My problem is, if I click the `#click2` then the `#click1` is selected too.

How can I make it only select `#click2` without calling `#click1`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('a#click2').click(function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

})
```

you can call stopPropagation, to prevent event bubbling up the DOM tree.